# Using a subquery with NOT IN

Tags: sql, ms-access

Find out how many books in the database are not part of the order.

Query:

```
SELECT COUNT(title)
FROM book INNER JOIN orders ON book.isbn = orders.bookID
WHERE isbn NOT IN (bookID);
```

Comment: Please edit. `NOT IN` is not a function, it's an operator (or two, depending how you look at it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would lean away from using `NOT IN` here. Learn to use `JOIN`:.

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM
   book AS B
   LEFT JOIN orders AS O
      ON B.isbn = O.bookID
WHERE
   O.isbn IS NULL
;
```

And also (not 100% sure this will work in Access but I think so):

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM
   book AS B
WHERE
   NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM orders AS O
      WHERE B.isbn = O.bookID
   )
;
```

Note that you don't need `Count(title)`, `Count(*)` works fine and doesn't cast doubt that perhaps you're trying to count the number of non-NULL titles.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a subquery and NOT IN, then you should write it this way

```
SELECT COUNT(title)
FROM book 
WHERE isbn NOT IN (SELECT bookID
                   FROM orders)
```